# Inserting data from AJAX request into MySQL database using FLASK app doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a sign-up form and send a POST request using AJAX with user data to the server. Then I run my Flask app where `signUp()` function is defined. This function should insert the received data into MySQL database.
Here is the source code of signup page:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Welcome to Terminology portal!</h1>
        <form id="form-signin">
        <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="inputName" id="inputName" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" placeholder="Email" required> 
        <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </form>
      </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#btnSignUp').click(function() {
 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/signUp',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the source code of flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

mysql = MySQL() 
app = Flask(__name__)
# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'Pankukas81811!'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'term_portal'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = '127.0.0.1'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')

@app.route('/signUp', methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    # read the posted values from the UI
    try:
        
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']
        
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        
        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:

            _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (login, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (_name, _hashed_password, _email))
            conn.commit()
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            
            if len(data) == 0:
                conn.commit()
                return json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
            else:
                return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

However the user is not added into database table. If I insert values instead of variables `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (login, password, email) VALUES ('Alex', 'qwerty', 'test@example.com')")` it works. When I define variables `_name, _password, _email` (like `_name = 'Alex'` instead of `_name = request.form['inputName']`) it doesn't work. So I suppose variables are not recognized inside of SQL query.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (login, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (_name, _hashed_password, _email))
```

If you want to interpolate the arguments into the query string, it has to look like this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (login, password, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (_name, _hashed_password, _email))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I corrected the query, but it still didn't work. However I found the root cause finally: a generated hashed password was too long. I changed password type in SQL from VARCHAR(50) to VARCHAR(100) and it solved the issue.